# report server timeout after 1.5 minutes in browser

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I desperately need help/suggestions

I'm not sure if this question is ok for SO, so sorry in advance...

well, problem is:

I have this one report in visual studio 2013 ( which doesn't really matter )

and it has a subquery

the query itself takes ~5 seconds

but hence it's in a sub

```
time dataretrieval = 33343  

time processing = 388703  

and time rendering = 22
```

the problem is that NONE of the browsers show the result

all of them just stop (i don't know what to call it, render? the thing that keeps on circling just stops ) after 1 minute 30 seconds.

I checked if I have timeouts anywhere

some said 1800 seconds, changed it to 0 and higher, still 1.5 minute dead end.

please, I'm open to suggestions.

the subquery generates ~300-500 excel pages

it works in VS itself

and even in browsers, when I check ExecutionLog2 it says success but no data is shown in the browser(s)

thanks guys & sorry if inappropriate.

Comment: SSRS doesn't cope very well with this many rows/pages. How long does it take in preview in VS?

Comment: ~5-8 minutes in VS

Comment: Have you considered optimising the query further? You mention its a subquery but the query performance as a whole is important. Also have you tried running it on a schedule (exported to excel or similar) and does that work? You might want to consider an alternative (SSIS job export to Excel) after trying these kinds of suggestions, if SSRS isn't the right tool for the job.